# how we can search all records using NSPredicate rather than setting fetchController nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am showing all the records in `UITableView` easily by using:

```
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Memo" inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"memodate" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

And for Searching records I am performing this:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

if (self.searchBar.text ==nil || [self.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    self.fetchedResultsController=nil;
}
else
{
    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"memodesc CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.searchBar.text];
    [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

}

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    // Handle error
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();  // Fail
}

[self.tableView reloadData];}
```

My Question is what is the right way to search all records if searchText value is `nil` or `""`

I am setting         `self.fetchedResultsController=nil;`  again for retrieving all the initial results.

But I don't think so this is the right way. It should be doable with predicate ?

**Update**:

Its working finw with this predicate

```
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1=1"];
        [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

But my app is crashing if I used this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"All"];
[_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

Unable to parse the format string "ALL"'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set the predicate to `nil` if you want to fetch all entities.

Answer (score 18):

And in swift:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
```

Answer (score 12):

I know it's an old thread, but anyway...You can also use:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
```

[Predicate format syntax in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

Comment: This answer should be used as some methods such as CKQuery initializers cannot have nil predicates

Comment: This worked for me when the others did not.